# trying to do apt-get with docker, causing error 100

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, graphicsmagick

I have a node.js application that I'm dockerizing, and it has a system dependency magicgraph. I cannot seem to be able to install it, I've tried apt-get in the Dockerfile like so `RUN apt-get install --force-yes -y graphicsmagick` and a few variations, but I keep getting the error `The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install --force-yes -y graphicsmagick' returned a non-zero code: 100`.

Not sure how to fix this, is there a step tutorial on how to install gz files with the `http://www.graphicsmagick.org/INSTALL-unix.html` url maybe?

Comment: did you RUN apt-get -y update before the install command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need update list of available packages before install new one.

replace `RUN apt-get install --force-yes -y graphicsmagick`
to

`RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y graphicsmagick`

if it don`t fix the issue show logs please